# 'object' does not contain a definition for 'ToDateTime'

Tags: c#, datetime

I am writing a script which takes data from fields. And I want to convert them to `DateTime`. here is the code:

```
Document.Field("Document Section 1\\Verification Date").Value.ParseExact();
```

and

```
Document.Field("Document Section 1\\Verification Date").Value.ParseExact();
```

I have tried `ParseExact`, `ToDateTime`, `TryParse`, and every time the error is the same.

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'ParseExact'

I am not a C# rockstar, so I will be grateful if you show me right way, not only theritacally, but with code.

Comment: What `Document.Field("Document Section 1\\Verification Date").Value` returns as a type and value exactly?

Comment: Obviously `Document.Field("...").Value` returns an `object`. Depending on what API you're using and which extension methods it contains, `ToDateTime()` may or may not be a viable extension method for `object`.  What API are you using and why do you expect `ToDateTime` to work? If the returned object actually is a DateTime, you can cast it as such; if not, you'll need to parse it. If the API you're using _does_ contain extension methods, all that may be wrong is simply a `using` directive to import the extension method.

Comment: @CodeCaster I have an external dll file, where overloads show what types and objects I have. In this script I am calling it. the overload is ...DateTime veriDate...

Comment: @clorkster string does not contain that method.

Comment: @plasmid Forgive me, you are correct.  I've had too much time using vb.net apparently.  Convert.ToDateTime(_YOUR_VALUE_) would work.  Your issue is the fact that your value doesn't have an explicit datatype, so object is assumed.  While some languages (such as the aformentioned VB.NET) are fine with that, C# is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what the Value is but

```
Document.Field("Document Section 1\\Verification Date").Value
```

will return a `object`.

What you need is a String. This string can then be parsed to DateTime
So a solution would be

```
DateTime.Parse(((String)Document.Field("Document Section 1\\Verification Date").Value)
```

Sidenote: Doesn't `DateTime.Parse` accept `object` too?

Comment: After I have checked this code an alarm ocured that it doesn't recognize the string, and I have added System assembly(previously ihad only System.IO imported), but this is the new alarm.

'string' does not contain a definition for 'ToDateTime'

Comment: already corrected that... ^^ but somehow i got it managed to NOT edit my other ansewer... (deleted it now... sorry for the useless data in the database @SO :D )

Comment: God bless you Mischa))